# Como remover o ponto (.) de um array de carateres?

Tags: c

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que lê um linha inteira pega os últimos três valores e substitui a virgula por ponto e depois transforma este numero para double. Porém não estou conseguindo desenvolver um método caso o número seja, por exemplo, `1**.**345,50`.

O ponto precisa ser excluído nesses casos primeiro para que eu consiga depois substituir a virgula por ponto e, subsequente, transformar em double.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 500

double strtodouble (char *array[MAX_LINE], int position){
    double num;
    char *ptr;

    ptr = strpbrk(array[position], ","); //retorna um ponteiro para a posição da string "," 
    if(ptr != NULL)   *ptr = '.';          //faz a substituição da ',' por '.'  
    num = atof(array[position]);       //converte string para float printf("num = %f", num);

    return num;

}

int main(void)
{

    char sFrase[]="1337-000/2018 01/10/2018 KI BARATO MERCEARIA DE DESCONT SECRETARIA DA CAMARA SECRETARIA DA CAMARA AÇÃO LEGISLATIVA Dispensa - Isento Compras e Serviços 2.343,50 343,40 343,30";
    int count = 0;
    char *p = strtok(sFrase, " ");
    char *array[500];
    //float valor = atof(*array);
    char *ptr;
    double num1, num2, num3;

    while (p)
    {
      array[count] = p;

      p = strtok (NULL, " ");

      count++;
    }

    //printf("%s\n", array[cont-1]);
    //printf("%s\n", array[cont-2]);
    //printf("%s\n", array[cont-3]);   

    //array[cont-3] = 343,50
    //ptr=array[cont-3][3]

    num1 = strtodouble(array, count-3);
    printf("\nESTE É O VALOR EMPENHADO --> %2.2f", num1 );

    num2 = strtodouble(array, count-2);
    printf("\nESTE É O VALOR LiQUIDADO --> %2.2f", num2 );

    num3 = strtodouble(array, count-1);
    printf("\nESTE É O VALOR PAGO --> %2.2f\n", num3 );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas o que não está feito ? Ou por outras palavras, o que falta fazer ? Dá algum erro ?

Comment: Falta eu conseguir eliminar o ponto do numero  2.343,50.

Comment: Dentro da função strtodouble eu consegui substituir o ponto por 0. Agora eu não consigo pensar em como remover esse 0. Quero que ele remova o ponto e continue a leitura do numero. O numero está assim: 2.343,50 eu quero que ele fique 2343,50 ....

ptr = strpbrk(array[position], "."); //retorna um ponteiro para a posição da string "." 
    if(ptr != NULL){   *ptr = '0';          //faz a substituição da '.' por '0'
    

    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C não tem muitas funções já prontas a usar para determinado tipo de coisas, sendo este caso uma delas, o de remover um caratere num array de carateres. Tendo em conta que também pretende trocar a virgula por ponto é mais facil usar um laço/ciclo e fazer tudo de uma só vez manualmente.

Exemplo:

```
double strtodouble (char *array[MAX_LINE], int position){
    static char temp[MAX_LINE];
    int i, pos_temp = 0;
    for (i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if (array[position][i] == ','){ //se é virgula troca por ponto
            temp[pos_temp++] = '.';
        }
        else if (array[position][i] != '.'){ //se não for ponto coloca o caretere
            temp[pos_temp++] = array[position][i];
        }
    }
    temp[pos_temp] = '\0'; //terminador no novo

    return atof(temp); //atof agora direto no retorno
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/wHwk8L)

No exemplo acima optei por construir um novo array com todos os carateres que interessam. Como o ponto não interessa ele não é copiado para o novo array e por isso acaba por ser excluido indiretamente. Esta forma é mais simples do que tentar remover um caratere no meio, pois iria ser necessário puxar todos os carateres à direita uma casa para a esquerda.

Comment: Perfeito!! eu queria encontrar uma maneira de fazer separado as duas coisas, primeiro tirar o ponto e depois tirar a vírgula. Obrigada pela resolução! Rodou perfeitamente!